# Как сверстать вот такой блок : ? :

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

**Задача сверстать так чтоб бекграунд, в данном случае картинка с воздушными шарами, внизу блока там где якорь была как бы обрезана от центра в обе стороны под углом. Пробовал clip-path, но не шибко получается. Так как же ???**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вот так я пробывал реализовать :**

```
.start {
    position: relative;
    background: limegreen;
    clip-path: inset(4% 0% 14% 0%);
    clip-path: circle(600px at 50% 42% );
}
```

**И вот что получается (внизу): **

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**И вот что получается (вверху): **

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**К тому же clip-path обрезает изображение-элемент: якорь, внизу страницы**

Comment: Два обычных белых блока + `transform: rotate(15deg)` ?

Answer (score 1):

С этим справится SVG

Рисуем path по нужным координатам и присваиваем ему фон в виде pattern в котором изображение растянуто на 100% высоты и ширины на весь SVG документ

Смотрим результат

Всю картину можно увидеть з[десь](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/qBbeYVY?editors=1000)

```html
<body style="margin: 0;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 520">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" ></rect>
        <circle cx="500" cy="500" r="20" fill="#000"></circle>
    </mask>
    <pattern id="ptn" width="100%" height="100%">
      <image width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0"
             preserveAspectRatio="none"
             href="https://s2.best-wallpaper.net/wallpaper/3840x2160/1709/Brasov-Romania-meadows-field-mountains-grass-clouds_3840x2160.jpg"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <path d="M0,0 1000,0 1000,400 500,500 0,400z" mask="url(#mask)" fill="url(#ptn)"/>
  </svg>
```

Comment: По ссылке то ничего не видно ?

Comment: @YaroslavBondar разве не видно ? скорее всего заблочен вашим провайдером